# Intersection of $C^*$-algebras under addition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, ideals, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$ be an inclusion of unital $C^*$-algebras. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an unital simple subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$ which is under the image of a faithful conditional expectation from $\mathcal{A}$, i.e., there exists a unital completely positive projection $\Phi: \mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{C}$. Moreover, $\Phi(\mathcal{B})\subsetneq \mathcal{C}$. Suppose that $I\triangleleft\mathcal{A}$ is a non-trivial two sided closed ideal in $\mathcal{A}$.

Standing assumption: $\mathcal{A}$ is generated as a $C^*$-algebra by $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$.

Claim: $\mathcal{B}\subsetneq\mathcal{B}+I\subsetneq \mathcal{A}$.

Attempt: Since $I\triangleleft\mathcal{A}$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{A}$, it follows that $I+\mathcal{B}$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$. Now, $\Phi(I)\triangleleft\mathcal{C}$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{C}$. Since $\mathcal{C}$ is simple, it follows that $\Phi(I)=0$ or $\Phi(I)=\mathcal{C}$. Since $\Phi$ is faithful, it must be the case that $\Phi(I)=\mathcal{C}$. Since $\Phi(\mathcal{B})\subsetneq \mathcal{C}$, it follows that $\mathcal{B}\subsetneq \mathcal{B}+I$.

Now, $I\cap\mathcal{C}$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{C}$. Since $\mathcal{C}$ is simple and $I$ is non-trivial, it must be the case that $I\cap\mathcal{C}=0$. Here, I am using the assumption that $\mathcal{A}$ is generated by $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$. All that remains to be shown is that $\mathcal{B}+I\subsetneq \mathcal{A}$. I am trying to show that $\left(\mathcal{B}+I\right)\cap \mathcal{C}=\mathcal{B}\cap\mathcal{C}$. Once this is establishes, we shall have that $\mathcal{B}\cap\mathcal{C}\subset \Phi(\mathcal{B})\subsetneq\mathcal{C}$ which will ensure that $\mathcal{B}+I\subsetneq \mathcal{A}$.

I am unable to do it. I need to use that $I\cap\mathcal{C}=0$. How do I do it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If $I\cap \mathcal{C}=\mathcal{C}$, then $\mathcal{C}\subset I$. Since $I$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{A}$, it would follow that $C^*(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C})\subset I$ which would imply that $I=\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: How do you get a contradiction from $\mathcal{B}+I=\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Ignore what I said.  Given that $\mathcal C$ is unital and $\Phi$ is faithful, $\mathcal C$ contains the unit of $A$.  Thus $I\cap\mathcal C=\mathcal C$ implies $I$ contains the unit of $\mathcal A$ and hence $I=\mathcal A$.

Comment: We can assume that they have the same unit.

Comment: Yes, because $\Phi$ is faithful.  What I'm saying is that you don't need to assume $\mathcal A= C^*(\mathcal B,\mathcal C)$ to conclude that $I\cap\mathcal C=0$.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for pointing that out.